# Make C# the default Page Language in Application Page (Sharepoint)

Tags: c#, vb.net, sharepoint

I have a problem in making an application page in my sharepoint project. When I tried making an aspx page and tried to view the code, the default Page Language is in VB and I want it to be in C# since I was exposed more in C# than in VB..

Kindly see Screenshot below.

[The screenshot is on this link.](http://dc368.4shared.com/img/-0BMSoV1/s7/0.29044049966701047/PageLanguageVB.png?async)[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Import Selected Environment Settings... -> Make selection whether to save current settings -> Select C# under the default setting folder

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I was so careless that I overlooked that I am making an empty sharepoint project in an other languages template.. My bad.. :)))